# What parts of the raw e-mail can be changed for the DKIM to stay valid?

Tags: email, dkim

Subj:

**Which parts of a raw e-mail message can be changed by a forwarding mail server for its DKIM signature to stay valid?**

Or, alternatively:

**What parts of the letter are signed by DKIM (and thus cannot be changed)?**

For the purpose of the question, I assume that the entire message has been signed by the sending server (no `l=` parameter).

I'm interested in a general answer because I didn't find a clear one at either [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) or [DKIM FAQ](http://www.dkim.org/info/dkim-faq.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Studying RFC 6376, and ultimately, its [section 3.7. Computing the Message Hashes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.7), I conclude:

> DKIM signature covers the message's body and the headers listed in the `h=` field.

So, all other headers can be added/edited so long as they don't clash with those covered by the signature.